# Load data from table to html form after hitting edit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have html form to save the data and also i have list of records in the database in the form table below the form.

The table has operations columns which has EDIT and DELETE operations. When user clicks edit option the corresponding row data has to copy to the html form.

I have the jsfiddle part to show the format please help to write the jquery.

```
<form>
ID: <input type="text" name="sid" id="sid"> <br/>
NAME: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"> <br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="SAVE"> 
</form>

<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>OPERATIONS</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr><td>1001</td><td>XYZ</td>
<td><a href="#">EDIT</a></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rvp_cse/owhx6kv2/

Answer (score 1):

Give some class to your edit link and to the sid and name `td`'s

```js
$('table').on('click','.edit_link',function(e){
   var row = $(this).closest('tr');
   $('#sid').val(row.find('.sid_val').text());
   $('#fname').val(row.find('.fname_val').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
ID: <input type="text" name="sid" id="sid"> <br/>
NAME: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"> <br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="SAVE"> 
</form>

<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>OPERATIONS</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr><td class='sid_val'>1001</td><td class="fname_val">XYZ</td>
<td><a class='edit_link' href="#">EDIT</a></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to change the form action url also. how to do that bro

Comment: You want to change based on the values in edit link row?

Comment: You can update the form action in the click handler like this `$('form').attr("action","myAction?sid="+row.find('.sid_val').text());`. But why do you want to set id in action url you can submit it along the POST form

Comment: Select2 not correctly selecting the data after click. It works good in normal select

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#edit').click(function(){
        $('#sid').val($('table td:eq(0)').html());
    $('#fname').val($('table td:eq(1)').html());
  });
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15s5z4j5/10/)

**Note:** Don't forget to include jquery library

Answer (score 1):

Add jquery and then

```
$(".edit").click(function(e) {      
        var sid = $(this).closest('tr').find(".sid").text();
    var fname = $(this).closest('tr').find(".fname").text();    
    $("#sid").val(sid);
    $("#fname").val(fname);
})

<form>
ID: <input type="text" name="sid" id="sid"> <br/>
NAME: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"> <br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="SAVE"> 
</form>

<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>OPERATIONS</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr><td class="sid">1001</td><td class ="fname">XYZ</td>
<td><a class="edit" href="#">EDIT</a></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```